# how accept lowercase and uppercase for string data input in python?

Tags: python

**ask user to enter registration type** 
Hi I tried to make the if condition accept the answer when the user enters it in lowercase or uppercase

```
reg = input("\nRegistration type (single or family): ")
```

Comment: for checking uppercase:
if (reg.isupper()):
    print("upper-case")

for checking lowercase:
if (reg.islower()):
    print("lower-case")

Comment: @YUVI_1303  but I NEED the code to accept the answer was in uppercase or in lowercase (single or family) or (SINGLE or FAMILY)


-- Also not accept it was "" of another word

Comment: is it an accepted solution now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg = input("\nRegistration type (single or family): ") 

if reg in ['single', 'family', 'SINGLE', 'FAMILY']:
    if reg.isupper():
        print("accepted in uppercase")
    elif reg.islower():
        print("accepted in lowercase")
else:
    print("not accepted")
```

working code

Answer (score 0):

you can use argparse for the input parameter, then use either upper() or lower() method to do input validation.

```
import argparse

def get_reg_input():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get User Input')
   parser.add_argument('-r', '--registration', help='Registration type', \
                       type=str, required=True, dest='input')
   return parser

def main():
   parser = get_reg_input()
   args = parser.parse_args()

   if args.input.lower() in ["single", "family"]:
      print("input is ok")
   else:
      print("value must be either 'single' or 'family'")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to validate the input using `while` and use `casefold()` to accept for uppercase or lowercase:

```
while not (reg := input("\nRegistration type (single or family): ").casefold()) in ('single', 'family'):
    print('Try again')
print(f'Registration type : {reg}')

# Registration type (single or family): double
# Try again

# Registration type (single or family): SINGLE
# Registration type : single


# Registration type (single or family): Not sure
# Try again

# Registration type (single or family): family
# Registration type : family
```